# Getting and setting attributes with Kendo sortable on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

Would just like to get and set different attributes when a list item is moved to the other list on my mvc page... I can't access anything so far.  The problem is in the javascript, it hits the onchange event fine. I didnt post the "available list" in the cshtml for brevity. this is what the console.log as the bottom reads:

> SpecialNeedInActiveList change:  Meds per tube  newIndex: -1 oldIndex: 5 action: remove
>   SpecialNeedActiveList change:  Meds per tube  newIndex: 3 oldIndex: -1 action: receive

Any help would be appreciated, this has taken way too long for me.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="SpecialNeedContainerLL">
            <ul id="SpecialNeedActiveList" class="col-md-6">
                @if (Model.SelectedSpecialNeeds.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var y in Model.SelectedSpecialNeeds)
                    {
                        <li class="list-item" selected-personspecialneed="@y.PersonSpecialNeedId" selected-need-type="@y.SpecialNeedTypeId"> @y.SpecialNeedDescription </li>
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
 @(Html.Kendo().Sortable()
.For("#SpecialNeedActiveList")
.ConnectWith("#SpecialNeedInActiveList")
.PlaceholderHandler("placeholder")
.Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
    )
```

**Javascript:**

```
function onChange(e) {
var id = e.sender.element.attr("id"),
    text = e.item.text(),
    newIndex = e.newIndex,
    oldIndex = e.oldIndex;

if (id == 'SpecialNeedActiveList' && newIndex > -1) {

    //add item to selected list
    //remove item from availables list

    /*NONE of the following works...*/
    //var oldPersonSpecialNeedId = e.sender.element.getAttribute('available-personspecialneed');
    //var oldSpecialNeedTypeId = e.sender.element.getAttribute('available-need-type');
    //e.sender.element.removeAttribute('available-personspecialneed');
    //e.sender.element.removeAttribute('available-need-type');
    //e.sender.element.setAttribute('selected-personspecialneed', oldPersonSpecialNeedId);
    //e.sender.element.setAttribute('selected-need-type', oldSpecialNeedTypeId);
}
console.log(id + " change: " + text + " newIndex: " + newIndex + " oldIndex: " + oldIndex + " action: " + e.action);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in the change event handler(onChange()), e.sender.element is NOT the item that was dragged, it is the list that sent the change event, the `<ul>` element.

The item being drag/dropped is contained in the e.item field, which you should be able to manipulate as normal, for example using jQuery(but you may use whatever DOM manipulation technique you like):

```
var $item = $(e.item);

var oldPersonSpecialNeedId = $item.attr('selected-personspecialneed');
var oldSpecialNeedTypeId = $item.attr('selected-need-type');
$item.attr("selected-personspecialneed", "new" + oldPersonSpecialNeedId);
$item.attr("selected-need-type", "new" + oldSpecialNeedTypeId);
```

Here's a working example showing the attributes being changed:http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/arUpO

It is based on single list from the code in your question rather than 2 lists  but it simply demonstrates how to access the dragged element from the sortable change event, which is the core of your problem.

Having said that, I would probably investigate using a DataSource-bound list so that you can manipulate fields of a model instead of attributes of a DOM element.  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/sortable/integration-listview is a good place to start.

Comment: Am I able to use $this?

Comment: You can.  In the context of the change sortable event, "this" is a reference to the sortable. So e.item and this.draggedElement both refer to the DOM element that was dragged.  It makes no difference how you get the reference to the dragged element, just as long as you get it.  I prefer e.item because it is the event telling you directly "here is the item that was dragged", whereas this.draggedElement is *conceptually* more indirect to me...personal preference.

Comment: So, where can I research e.item, e.text.... I guess I'd like to know what all tools I have at my disposal to use...  Thank you for your help btw

Comment: I don't know about e.text but e.item is in the kendo documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/sortable#events-change.  Every API call, event, object, etc is slightly different and has its own documentation that you need to read.  But also, one of the more useful ways is to simply explore the object(e, or whatever) in the browser dev tools.